# Python Library for Boyer-Myrvold planarity test or Kuratowski subgraph identification

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx, planar-graph

I am working with NetworkX Graphs in Python and I would like to find the Kuratowski subgraphs of any given graph which I have.

The Boyer-Myrvold planar graph testing algorithm can return an existing  Kuratowski subgraph if the graph is not planar (O(n) in the number of vertices n), so I was hoping that there might already be an implementation of that algorithm or of a similar algorithm in Python. I have been so far unable to find one and I am slightly reluctant at having to re-implement it from the original research paper.

It is even better if it can easily interface with NetworkX library for graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Python wrapper for part of of John Boyer's planarity code (https://code.google.com/p/planarity/) that might be what you are looking for.
It is at https://github.com/hagberg/planarity.

It has a NetworkX interface that allows you to test for planarity and find the Kurotowski subgraphs if not.  e.g.

https://github.com/hagberg/planarity/blob/master/examples/networkx_interface.py

```
import planarity
import networkx as nx
# Example of the complete graph of 5 nodes, K5
G=nx.complete_graph(5)
# K5 is not planar
print(planarity.is_planar(G)) # False
# find forbidden Kuratowski subgraph
K=planarity.kuratowski_subgraph(G)
print(K.edges()) # K5 edges
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks really promissing, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I get the following error while trying to import it:
import planarity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./planarity/planarity/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .planarity import PGraph
ImportError: No module named planarity

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem might stem from the fact that planarity is a .pyx file and not a .py file??

Comment: Ok. I solved the problem with the following steps:

Comment: sudo apt-get install cython

Comment: and before importing planarity

Comment: import pyximport
pyximport.install()

Comment: but now I get the following error while trying to import:

Comment: ImportError: Building module planarity.planarity failed: ["CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1\n"]

Comment: actually the error is 
/.pyxbld/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyrex/planarity/planarity.c:349:33: fatal error: src/graphStructures.h: No such file or directory
 #include "src/graphStructures.h"

Comment: it is strange, because the ./planarity/src/graphStructures.h file is there.

Comment: apparently I've been complicating my life uselessly by cloning the git and importing from there. sudo pip install planarity workes and allows import.